# Is it thread-safe to allocate a memory with new?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory, thread-safety

If I have some function that create new objects and return it's id, ignoring for now the moment how I will store this pointer

```
int foo()
{
   SomeClass *p = new SomeClass();
   return p->id();
}
```

Imagine only this meaningless code snippet, will it be tread-safe? If two threads come almost simultaneously into the function, there is no way that they will try to allocate memory in the same(intersected) place? And calling method by pointer should be also thread-safe, as we are just reading the memory.

Comment: The duplicate doesn't cover second question (" And calling method by pointer should be also thread-safe..."), but this is why it is preferred to have one question for post.

Comment: The dupe covers your main question but whether or not the code shown is thread-safe depends on the implementation of `SomeClass`.

Comment: @SergeyA the method just return the number, nothing more

Comment: @G.M. in c-tor only initializing id. And id() just returns number